# Pricing table: <div>'s do not align when an <li> element is removed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a pricing table with 4 sections. The `div`'s I created work fine until an `li` element is removed. The whole box shifts down and does not align. It's worth mentioning that I am using bootstrap.

I have tried:

- forcing a position
- removing margins/padding
- Setting width/height
- Leaving empty `<li></li>` (sort of works, but doesn't align property)

Here is my code: http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/xlaibrry

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show a working jsFiddle or codepen, so we can start playing around with the code.

Comment: You can also work with the code on cssdeck. It seems the preferred method is jsFiddle, so I'll use that in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add vertical-align:top to the boxes:

```
.whole{
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add  .`whole` - `vertical-align: top`